# Draw on map a feature already present with its information in the attribute tables

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, editing, map-drawing

I know how to add a feature, whatever the geometry, to a layer, by drawing it on the map (e.g. with the Add Polygon Feature): once the geometry is completed, a window for inputting its attributes is prompted so that all the needed information can be added.

However, I can't figure how to draw on map a feature that is already present in my attribute table with all information. I saw that the Add Part button (available in Edit Mode) allows drawing a polygon vertex after vertex, but what if I need a circular shape?

Comment: Is the attribute table a text file that has been imported to qgis as a delimited text layer and has no coordinate data?  Or a non-spatial geopackage layer?

Comment: It is a polygon geopackage layer. Some features already have their shapes in the map (because I first drew them and then added their info). I'm struggling to draw on map the features already present in the table. Add Part seems to be an-almost-solution, however in some cases my feature should be perfectly circular and I don't know how to do that with Add Part (Add Circle would add a completely new feature).

Comment: Sorry - I'm not familiar with a polygon geopackage layer that has records but no geometry. Not sure how you created that.

Comment: If you are able to use the Add Part tool - then you can use the shape digitising toolbar to add circles - select the record you want to add the geometry for before digitising the associated circle.

Comment: Thanks, but as I wrote the option Add Circle (available in the Shape Digitizing Toolbar) adds a new feature, it doesn't let me draw for an existing (in the table) selected feature.

Comment: Ok - I see the problem.  Don't think I can help.  I would never digitise this way!  Have you many features to create?

Comment: I also consider it an unusual approach. I basically created a geopackage for an interactive use where I and my team can store all our projects that interest different areas of the city (each one a feature that can directly link to related folders and files using the actions I created). So it can happen someone has already inserted a new entry in the table of the gpkg, but it may still need to be mapped (digitized).

Comment: Not sure what to suggest!  You could separate out the attributes to non-spatial table and have geometry separate and then join by a key field (not fid)..